# Writing the relationships of group elements in terms of modular arithmetic

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Consider a group $G$ of order $pq$ (like ($\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_q$,+)), where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, and two elements $g_1, g_2 \in G$. Suppose $|g_1|=p$ and $|g_2|=q$. These two elements satisfy the relation,

$g_1^m g_2^n =e$, where $e$ is the identity element of $G$.

Then can we write as,

$m \equiv 0 (mod p)$

$n \equiv 0 (mod q)$ ?

If it is possible can someone please explain why it is possible? This is not clear to me..

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What is $g$ in $g^mg^n=e$?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake. Thanks @brj I corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a useful result in group theory: $\forall x\in G$, and $m, n\in \mathbb{Z}$, if $x^n = 1$ and $x^m = 1$, then $x^{(m, n)} = 1$ (where $(m, n)$ denotes the greatest common divisor of $m$ and $n$). To see why this holds, observe that $(m,n) = mx+ny$ for suitable $x$ and $y$ (see [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) for how). Now from this it follows that $\forall m\in\mathbb{Z}, x^m = 1\iff |x|$ divides m. Since to say that $n$ divides $m$ is to say that $m\equiv 0(mod n)$, the rest follows.

Comment: Thank you very much @brj . That means from $g_1^m g_2^n =e$, we can get $g_1^m=e \rightarrow (1)$ and $g_2^n=e \rightarrow (2)$. And then using (1) and $g_1^p=e$ we get $m \equiv 0 (mod p)$ and using (2) and $g_2^q=e$ we can get $n \equiv 0 (mod q)$ ?

Comment: From (1) can we also take as $g_1^m=g_1^p$ and then get $m \equiv p (mod p)$ as well? And same for (2), as $n \equiv q (mod q)$?

Comment: @BobTraver no, that is incorrect $g_1^mg_2^n$ does not imply $g_1^m$ and $g_2^n$ are $e$ (they can be inverses of each other)

Comment: Ok, @brj but then in my question I know the relation $g_1^m g_2^n =e$ only, then how can I apply the above answer to get $m \equiv 0 (mod p)$ and $n \equiv 0 (mod q)$?